# Is the idiom "at x year old" incorrect?

Tags: grammar

I thought about writing the sentence "She underwent surgery at 4 year old.", but I thought it sounded weird without seeming technically wrong, but is it? I definitively think "She underwent surgery at age 3" sounds better, but I would like to know why the former is wrong if it is.

Comment: We'd say "at 4 year**s** old", but otherwise it sounds fine to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"She underwent surgery at 4 year**s** old." is fine, but note that "years" should be plural because we are talking about 4 of them.

We do have an idiomatic expression which is an exception to that concept (i.e. plural "years"). A "4 year old" or (hyphenated sometimes) "4-year-old" is a 3-word noun meaning a child who is 4 year**s** old.

So you could say,

> "She underwent surgery **as a** 4 year old."
>
> "She underwent surgery at 4 year**s** old."
>
> "She underwent surgery at age 4."

All three sound equally natural to me.